# Extending a neural network for non binary classification using PyMC

Tags: python, pymc

This is originally coming from [here](https://www.pymc.io/projects/examples/en/latest/variational_inference/bayesian_neural_network_advi.html) which is used for a binary classification using variational inference,

```py
def construct_nn(X_train, Y_train, 
                 floatX=pytensor.config.floatX, 
                 rng=np.random.default_rng(2), 
                 n_hidden=5):

    # Initialize random weights between each layer
    init_1 = rng.standard_normal(size=(X_train.shape[1], n_hidden)).astype(floatX)
    init_2 = rng.standard_normal(size=(n_hidden, n_hidden)).astype(floatX)
    init_out = rng.standard_normal(size=n_hidden).astype(floatX)

    coords = {
        "hidden_layer_1": np.arange(n_hidden),
        "hidden_layer_2": np.arange(n_hidden),
        "train_cols": np.arange(X_train.shape[1]),
        # "obs_id": np.arange(X_train.shape[0]),
    }
    with pm.Model(coords=coords) as neural_network:
        ann_input = pm.Data("ann_input", X_train, mutable=True, dims=("obs_id", "train_cols"))
        ann_output = pm.Data("ann_output", Y_train, mutable=True, dims="obs_id")

        # Weights from input to hidden layer
        weights_in_1 = pm.Normal(
            "w_in_1", 0, sigma=1, initval=init_1, dims=("train_cols", "hidden_layer_1")
        )

        # Weights from 1st to 2nd layer
        weights_1_2 = pm.Normal(
            "w_1_2", 0, sigma=1, initval=init_2, dims=("hidden_layer_1", "hidden_layer_2")
        )

        # Weights from hidden layer to output
        weights_2_out = pm.Normal("w_2_out", 0, sigma=1, initval=init_out, dims="hidden_layer_2")

        # Build neural-network using tanh activation function
        act_1 = pm.math.tanh(pm.math.dot(ann_input, weights_in_1))
        act_2 = pm.math.tanh(pm.math.dot(act_1, weights_1_2))
        act_out = pm.math.sigmoid(pm.math.dot(act_2, weights_2_out))

        # Binary classification -> Bernoulli likelihood
        out = pm.Bernoulli(  
            "out",
            act_out,
            observed=ann_output,
            total_size=Y_train.shape[0],  # IMPORTANT for minibatches
            dims="obs_id",
        )
    return neural_network
```

for non binary classification: I used `pm.Categorical`,
but actually

```py
neural_network = construct_nn(X_train, Y_train)
with neural_network:
    approx = pm.fit(n=30000)
approx.hist # gives an array of inf
```

for a toy example to test I used Iris dataset:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
```

and reduced the dimension of features to 2 but I am not this was necessary:

```py
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
X_2d = tsne.fit_transform(X)
X = scale(X_2d)
X = X.astype(floatX)
Y = Y.astype(floatX)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y , test_size=0.3)
```

Do you have any Idea?

here is a link to the notebook in [drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11NImZsfQQM6sdxPf0IrLBV4AKngsrSQa/view?usp=sharing)